# Get transitive members using delta query

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a group (GROUP 1) containing one user (USER 1) and one group (GROUP 2). GROUP 2 contains 2 users (USER 2 and USER 3). When I run delta query graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id eq 'GROUP 1', response includes USER 1 and GROUP 2. Is there a way to get response as USER1, USER 2, USER 3?

Code:

```
var a = await grapgClient
                      .Groups
                      .Delta()
                      .Request()
                      .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")
                      .Top(MaxResultCount)
                      .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

For tracking the changes in groups using the delta query for groups please refer this example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,description,members
```

Please refer this document for more information on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#example-track-changes-to-groups

Hope this helps.